# I cannot retrieve data from form to Django class. Cannot get data from object with using form field value

Tags: django-forms, searchview, django-class-based-views

**This is the HTML file**

```html
<form action="{% url 'invDrugs:invDrugs-search' %}" method="GET" id="form1"></form>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search"  name="search" class="form-control ">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
</div>
</form>
```

**this is the url path**

```
path('search/', InvDrugsSearchView.as_view(), name='invDrugs-search')
```

**this is the class**

```py
class InvDrugsSearchView(ListView):
    model = InvDrugs
    template_name = "invDrugs/search.html"
    def get_queryset(self): # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('search')
        object_list = InvDrugs.objects.filter(Q(code=query))
        return object_list
```

As you can see, I am submitting the form then it should be go to this class `InvDrugsSearchView(ListView)` but nothing happend.

I just want to get this value and search it from the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing the `form` tag right there in the first line. This means that the text field and submit button are not part of the form.